# string to datetime conversion javascript

Tags: javascript

How do I convert string(09-Apr-2010) in to date time (09 April 2010 00:00:00) using java script? I need to compare the dates for validation.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

check out [Date.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Date/Parse)

```
str = "09-Apr-2010"
date = new Date(Date.parse(str.replace(/-/g, " ")))
alert(date.toLocaleString())
```

Comment: One caveat: Date.parse with ISO format dates ('2010-04-01') doesn't seem to work on IE7, although it works in Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Try this should work

```
<script language="javascript">
    function validateDate(oSrc, args)
    {
        var iDay, iMonth, iYear;
        var arrValues;
        arrValues = args.Value.split("/");
        iMonth = arrValues[0];
        iDay = arrValues[1];
        iYear = arrValues[2];

        var testDate = new Date(iYear, iMonth - 1, iDay);

        if ((testDate.getDate() != iDay) ||
            (testDate.getMonth() != iMonth - 1) ||
            (testDate.getFullYear() != iYear))
        {
            args.IsValid = false;
            return;
        }

        return true;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: np. I know it's old but I got here via Google so I figured others still may come :)